# Can I create an RSS feed of only my questions but that does not include answers I give to questions?

Tags: support, feed

Can I create an RSS feed of only my questions but that does not include answers I give to questions?  And vice-versa...rss feed for answers but not questions?

So can it be done?

Seth

Comment: I take it that this can't be done given the lack of answers?
Seth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cooked up a simple [Yahoo pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/jldugger/stackoverflow) that inspects the beginning of the title for "Comment by" and "Answer by". You can easily tweak it. Presumably your own questions aren't titled in a way to defeat that. It should be possible to parameterize by UID and site but I'll leave that up to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

This is trivial to implement using a small app I created called [stack2rss](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service).

For all of your questions:

> http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/meta.stackoverflow/users/39478/questions?body=true

For all your answers:

> http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/meta.stackoverflow/users/39478/answers?body=true